# How can I calculate a hash/checksum/fingerprint of an object in c++?

Tags: c++, hash, orm, checksum

How can I calculate a hash/checksum/fingerprint of an object in c++?

Requirements:

The function must be 'injective'(*). In other words, there should be no two different input objects, that return the same hash/checksum/fingerprint.

Background:

I am trying to come up with a simple pattern for checking whether or not an entity object has been changed since it was constructed. (In order to know which objects need to be updated in the database).

Note that I specifically do not want to mark the object as changed in my setters or anywhere else.

I am considering the following pattern: In short, every entity object that should be persisted, has a member function "bool is_changed()". Changed, in this context, means changed since the objects' constructor was called.

*Note: My motivation for all this is to avoid the boilerplate code that comes with marking objects as clean/dirty or doing a member by member comparison. In other words, reduce risk of human error.*

(Warning: psudo c++ code ahead. I have not tried compiling it).

```
class Foo {
private:

    std::string my_string;

    // Assume the "fingerprint" is of type long.
    long original_fingerprint;

    long current_fingerprint()
    {
        // *** Suggestions on which algorithm to use here? ***
    }
public:
    Foo(const std::string& my_string) :
        my_string(my_string)
    {
        original_fingerprint = current_fingerprint();
    }

    bool is_changed() const 
    {
        // If new calculation of fingerprint is different from the one
        // calculated in the constructor, then the object has  
        // been changed in some way.

        return current_fingerprint() != original_fingerprint;
    }

    void set_my_string(const std::string& new_string)
    {
        my_string = new_string;
    }
}


void client_code()
{
    auto foo = Foo("Initial string");

    // should now return **false** because 
    // the object has not yet been changed:
    foo.is_changed();

    foo.set_my_string("Changed string");

    // should now return **true** because
    // the object has been changed:
    foo.is_changed();
}
```

(*) In practice, not necessarily in theory (like uuids are not unique in theory).

Comment: It's probably easier to have a `bool dirty` to mark whether an object has been changed. If you use getters and setters in conjunction with private member variables you can almost always ensure that the object is properly marked. *Edit*: If you separate the data from the logic then you can always ensure the data is properly marked.

Comment: Thanks. However my primary goal with this is to avoid having to mark the object as dirty in my setters, since this is easily forgotten when adding new setters to the class.

Comment: C++ doesn't support (out of the box) reflection. You can't automatically generate a hash for new member variables. You will have to not forget to include it in your hash generation.

Comment: The 'injective'(*) requirement would require a duplicate of the object (and even then it could change and change back to the same).  The CRC will provide a high degree of fulfilling the requirement with a inverse probability to the size of the CRC.  However, the only way to know the data is exactly the same is to duplicate it (unless you can guarantee that only a subset of bits will change).  This is @davidv1992 answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [CRC32 algorithm from Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/crc). Feed it with the memory locations of the data you want to checksum. You could use a hash for this, but hashes are cryptographic functions intended to guard against intentional data corruption and are slower. A CRC performs better.

For this example, I've added another data member to `Foo`:

```
int my_integer;
```

And this is how you would checksum both `my_string` and `my_integer`:

```
#include <boost/crc.hpp>
// ...

long current_fingerprint()
{
    boost::crc_32_type crc32;
    crc32.process_bytes(my_string.data(), my_string.length());
    crc32.process_bytes(&my_integer, sizeof(my_integer));
    return crc32.checksum();
}
```

However, now we're left with the issue of two objects having the same fingerprint if `my_string` and `my_integer` are equal. To fix this, we should include the address of the object in the CRC, since C++ guarantees that different objects will have different addresses.

One would think we can use:

```
process_bytes(&this, sizeof(this));
```

to do it, but we can't since `this` is an rvalue and thus we can't take its address. So we need to store the address in a variable instead:

```
long current_fingerprint()
{
    boost::crc_32_type crc32;
    void* this_ptr = this;
    crc32.process_bytes(&this_ptr, sizeof(this_ptr));
    crc32.process_bytes(my_string.data(), my_string.length());
    crc32.process_bytes(&my_integer, sizeof(my_integer));
    return crc32.checksum();
}
```

Comment: Calculating CRC for an address will work just for the basic data types (such as integer or char ) when sizeof() returns the size of whole memory used by that data type.
for a complex data type (for example using STL data types) or data types that are allocated in the heap (using new() ) , the result will not cover the whole data type.

I think one solution could be using a binary serialization library (like Boost library), and calculate CRC on serialized data.

Comment: @user1916016 You can get a CRC for anything you want. Bytes are bytes. The type doesn't matter. Also, you're not calculating a CRC for an address here. You're calculating a CRC for a sequence of bytes that begins at that address.

Comment: to @user1916016:
yes you can calculate CRC of your data type very easy, if all of your data are stored consequently in one array of bytes but when you are using complicated data types, for example a class that its attributes, are created in heap memory, you can not access to your whole data through address of your object of your class:
->
class A
{
public:
  int* myint;
  A(){ myint = new int(0); }
  void change(int k) { *myint = k;}
}

A a;
int crc1 = CRC32(&a , sizeof(A));
a.change(10);
int crc2 = CRC32(&a , sizeof(A));
<-
in this example, crc1 will be equal to crc2 !

Comment: @user1916016 Correct. But `process_bytes()` makes a CRC of the data at the address, not of the address itself. `crc32.process_bytes(my_string.data(), my_string.length())` will make a CRC for the contents of the string. And `process_bytes(&my_integer, sizeof(my_integer))` will make a CRC out of the contents of the integer, not of the address of the integer. However, I just noticed that my code will produce the same CRC for two objects that have the same string contents and the same `my_integer` value. That one needs fixing :-)

Comment: @user1916016 I updated the answer to now also include the object's address to make the fingerprint unique.

Comment: I think you did miss a point of 'mohtashami740'.  If the object is not POD and/or has pointers to other classes/structures and those changed, then you would possibly want to have that data included.  It is a good point that the serialization (Ie, what would go to a database) is a good criteria for the OP.  However, I see your solution as possibly working for POD excluding pointers generically (or you don't care about pointed to data); but it needs this caveat.

Answer (score 3):

Such a function does not exist, at least not in the context that you are requesting.

The STL provides hash functions for basic types (std::hash), and you could use these to implement a hash function for your objects using any reasonable hashing algorithm.

However, you seem to be looking for an injective function, which causes a problem. Essentially, to have an injective function, it would be necessary to have an output of size greater or equal to that of the object you are considering, since otherwise (from the pigeon hole principle) there would be two inputs that give the same output. Given that, the most sensible option would be to just do a straight-up comparison of the object to some sort of reference object.

Comment: Thanks. Whould it be possible to calculate a hash of each member variable in the object, and then "sum" all of these in such a way that the sum is unique to each object? (By unique I mean probability of collisions almost zero - like a UUID).

Comment: @andrewib You can just use a good old [SHA2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2) (or [SHA3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-3)), a cryptographic hash function which is collision resistant (in other words, it is hard to find x,y s.t. SHA2(x) = SHA2(y)).